# yield produces syntax error, unexpected (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, yield

I am trying to create a function which will generate lines using yield. But I got this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$line' (T_VARIABLE)

```
$emails = file_get_contents("addresses.txt");
function yieldEmails($emails){
 $start_time = microtime(true);
 foreach ($emails as $i => $em):
   $line = array( "test@test.com", 12);
   yield $line;
 endforeach;
}

$indexes = yieldEmails($emails);
```

Can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: Is the variable `$offset` defined ?

Comment: what do the other functions do there?

Comment: OK, I have simplified the code inside the loop.

Comment: @JohnyBony There is no parse error with this code anymore. What exactly is the error message you get now and what is the current source code you have? And if relevant, add the PHP version you are using.

Comment: @Progman: Just change `$line = array( "test@test.com", 12);` and I got the parse error still. PHP 5.4

Comment: @JohnyBony "yield" was introduces in version 5.5, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks

Comment: @Dharman: Not possible. I am using Windows XP and not gonna change.